# How to store many audio files in android app

Tags: android, firebase, performance

I am working on a android app for audio stories. The app is very simple , it plays audio files. It was working ok until 10 stories (20MB total app size) , however I have started having issues when added more stories to it.

Please can someone suggest what is a better way of storing audio files , I will be having 3 to 4 GB of audio files size going forward, Is firebase an option ?

Thank you in advance .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow  [tour]. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [mcve] applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. Add the code you're using and the details of the errors or exceptions you might have.

Comment: You should store blobs (audio, video, images, pdfs etc) in [Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) and keep a reference to those files in the Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore.